# How to examine the relationship between a multiple response categorical variable and a continuous outcome?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, continuous-data

I have a questionnaire that asked people to endorse the top three types of internet based activity they engage in (binary yes/no for each category of activity, 22 categories).  I want to examine whether type of internet use is related to a continuous measure of social behaviors.  My first thought was linear regression, but as I understand it, I can't use dummy codes with multiple response data.  Thoughts on how to move forward?  There are 49 cases in the sample.

Comment: So, you have a continuous dependent variable, and 22 predictors (each 0 if they did not pick it, or 1 if they did).  There's no reason you couldn't use multiple regression except that you have only 49 cases. The rule of thumb is that you should have at least 10 cases for each variable. But it's likely that those 22 categories are correlated -- you might try a PCA (Principal Components Analysis) as a way to combine those 22 predictors into a smaller number. If that looks promising, a factor analysis might give you more interpretable factors.